# SQL Error 1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to enter some data for a user into my MySQL database. This is my SQL query.

`INSERT INTO player VALUES ('test', 'ANIDENTIFIER', 'ANOTHERID', 0);`

The first column is the primary key. When I execute the query I get the error, "Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'".

The database I am inserting into is empty, and the primary key I am trying to insert is 'test'. Where is the error coming from?

Comment: Any triggers..?

Comment: can you add your `player` table structure?

Comment: `Duplicate entry '1'` would seem to indicate that your pkey field is an int, not a string.

Comment: It's always good practice to use the full insert syntax that includes the field names; it protects your queries if fields get re-ordered, when new fields with defaults are added, and makes you query more self-documenting so the poor sap that has to maintain your code doesn't have to keep alt-tabbing between the code window and one that shows the database structure to find which one of your fields are being inserted incorrectly when one of the first two occurs...assuming he doesn't have to guess because no one recorded the original fields and their order.